# MYSQL PDO: Multiples users with the same rank. How to make the db structure?

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

First of all I'll tell you what I want to do.

First make a system role. That is (User, mod, admin, etc).

And add an option to add roles and these are stored in a different user table.

In better words. I need to know how to structure the database (tables) to match a role.

That is:

- All new must have the user role.
- If I am an administrator, I can add
  new roles and edit the user.
- A member may have a role.
- Roles can have many users.

  Divided into two tables:

  Site_table = stores ranges and site configurations.

  User_table = Store registration information and user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with 4 tables (only important information for this purpose added to tables):

```
users
  -- id
  -- role_id


roles
  -- id
  -- name


privileges
  -- id
  -- name
  -- value


privileges_to_roles
  -- privilege_id
  -- role_id
```

- Relationship users <-> roles is 1:n as one user should be related to one role.
- Relationship roles <-> privileges is n:m as one role should consist of lots of different privileges (e.g. writing articles, moderating new comments, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is what I need. How I can do relationship between tables?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the relationship between the `users` and the `roles` table is done via the `role_id` column in the `users` table. The relationship between the `roles` and the `privileges` table is done via the `privileges_to_roles` table. You just add a new entry to the `privileges_to_roles` table for every relationship between `roles` and `privileges`.